# What proportion of US government revenue came from taxes on slaves, between 1790 and 1846?

Tags: united-states, slavery, taxes

What proportion of US government revenue (federal,state,local) came from taxes on slaves between 1790 and 1846?

I chose 1846 as the breakpoint because of the [Walker Tariff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walker_tariff); feel free to critique that choice.

**Background:**

Based on [this paper](https://www.everycrsreport.com/files/20060925_RL33665_4a8c6781ce519caa3e6b82f95c269f73021c5fdf.pdf) (h/t to [Brian Z](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/3011/brian-z)), taxes on slaves did not seem to be important for the federal government during this period (unless they were subject to excise?).

[This paper](https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3284&context=jssw) discusses "disputes about the taxation of slaves" and seems to imply that they were often taxed as property in southern states. It does not discuss relative magnitudes, but it is what motivated the question.

Answer (score 7):

For its first seven decades the federal government was supported almost entirely by customs revenue, not taxes on slaves.

Slavery's most direct connection to taxation occurred at the state/local
level via property taxation. Einhorn's work on this topic is very
good. Additional sources on antebellum politics, slavery, and property
taxation can be found in the bibliography of [The Rise and Fall of Wealth Taxation](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/handle/2027.42/78949) -- a general work on US property taxation that includes
some coverage of the connections between slavery and property taxation (it
builds on Einhorn's work in that respect).

Comment: This answer seems to leave open the question of if the federal government received customs revenue on the import of slaves.

Comment: The US [banned the import of slaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Act_Prohibiting_Importation_of_Slaves#:~:text=The%20Act%20Prohibiting%20Importation%20of,by%20the%20United%20States%20Constitution.) in 1807, so that rules out any customs revenue on slaves after 1808.

Comment: @Dave In addition to the ban on slave imports, there is the conceptual matter. My sense is that 19th century Americans would not have placed slaves in the bucket of things appropriate to tax via tariff. In terms of the economic magnitude, slaves were **wealth** and the appropriate fiscal mechanism was property taxation. I have not investigated the narrow question directly (it's possible that somewhere in colonial or early republic, a small bit of customs revenue from slave imports existed), but it's just not a significant thing one sees in the literature on the history of US taxation.

Comment: @FMc I don't think you are correct on that score. Slaves were taxed via customs duties and probably made up a non-trivial share of that (since only imports and not exports were taxable and mostly the early U.S. was a net exporter of ordinary goods per the triangular trade).

Comment: Also worth observing that the U.S. government from 1776-1789 was funded by contributions to the federal government from state government tax collections under the Articles of Confederation, with the pertinent period of taxation under the current constitution from 1789-1807.

Comment: @ohwilleke The linked source does not focus on colonial and early republic taxation, but it does have a chapter summarizing it well enough and provides references to several other sources. Your description (re: slaves taxed via customs duties) does not align with the existing literature on the history of colonial and US taxation, both state and national, at least not regarding the most significant revenue sources.

Comment: Thanks @FMc, I will mark this as the answer in a few days just to let the question "breathe."